# Can every semi-algebraic set be written as a finite union of disjoint Nash submanifolds?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

Can we write every semi-algebraic set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ as the disjoint union of finitely many Nash submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^m$? By Nash submanifolds are meant those manifolds that are smooth and semi-algebraic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a semi-algebraic cell decomposition does this already. Any of the usual texts on semi-algebraic geometry will prove this - for instance, Bochnak-Coste-Roy's *Real Algebraic Geometry* or Lou van den Dries' *Tame Topology and O-Minimal Structures* definitely have this, and both Michel Coste's notes on [o-minimal geometry](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/michel.coste/polyens/OMIN.pdf) or [semi-algebraic geometry](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/michel.coste/polyens/SAG.pdf) also contain proofs.